# Laravel returns blank page when view is returned in another method

Tags: php, laravel, methods, view, laravel-5

Hy guys,

I am working on a Laravel project and for the purpose of project structure I am trying to return a view by calling a method that is located in the same class as the function the triggers it. (see code)

Now this case works perfectly

```
public function pay()
{
    $navActive = true;
    return view('steps.pay', compact('navActive'));
}
```

But when I do something like this it will return a blank page

```
public function pay()
{
    $navActive = true;
    $this->test($navActive);
}

public function test($navActive)
{
    return view('steps.pay', compact('navActive'));
}
```

Please keep in mind that the name of the view is right, the view exists and if I use dd('with some message') inside the method that it is supposed to return the view, it will get triggered.

Any idea?, I spent so much time so far trying to find an answer, I am not sure what I am missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `test` method is only returning the view to the `pay` method - you also need to return from that:

```
public function pay()
{
    $navActive = true;
    return $this->test($navActive);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just forget "return"

```
public function pay()
{
    $navActive = true;
    return $this->test($navActive);
}

public function test($navActive)
{
    return view('steps.pay', compact('navActive'));
}
```